# Fedora 27 LXDE closing lid doesn't lock the screen (selinux acpid xscreensaver-command)

Tags: sockets, acpi, selinux, xscreensaver

I've installed acpid and setup an event for lid close which works in debug mode, however I cannot get it to work when acpid is started by systemd.

I used the suggestions here to configure acpid
[Linux suspend or sleep on lid close](https://superuser.com/questions/507180/linux-suspend-or-sleep-on-lid-close/1341360#1341360)

cat /etc/acpi/events/lid

```
event=button[ /]lid
action=/etc/acpi/actions/lid_down.sh %
```

cat /etc/acpi/actions/lid_down.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" = "button/lid" ] && [ "$2" = "LID" ] && [ "$3" = "close" ] && xscreensaver-command -lock
```

running **acpid -d -l** works, but **systemctl start acpid** produces the following error when I close the lid

```
# ausearch -m avc -ts recent -i
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 04:14:19.214:452) : avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=16632 comm=xscreensaver-co path=/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:xserver_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=0
```

What selinux policy do I require to allow xscreensaver-command access to my display socket when launched from acpid ?

================================================

So, I edited my script and I can get it to work as follows:

cat /etc/acpi/actions/lid_down.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

[ "$1" = "button/lid" ] && [ "$2" = "LID" ] && [ "$3" = "close" ] && /usr/local/bin/xscreensaver-lock-all
```

cat /usr/local/bin/xscreensaver-lock-all

```
#!/bin/bash

logger "screen saver lock script started"
for user in $(ps -ef | awk '($0~/xscreensaver/&&$0!~/awk/){print $1}')
do
    su $user -c "/usr/bin/xscreensaver-command -lock"
done
```

I did try inserting various runcon options into lid_down.sh, but to no avail. So my current workaround is:

```
# semanage permissive -a apmd_t
```

But that produces the following errors:

```
# ausearch -m avc -ts recent -i
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.266:287) : avc:  denied  { bind } for  pid=3372 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_selinux_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.266:286) : avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=3372 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_selinux_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.267:288) : avc:  denied  { compute_av } for  pid=3372 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:security_t:s0 tclass=security permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.268:292) : avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=3372 comm=su capability=setgid  scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.271:294) : avc:  denied  { setsched } for  pid=3372 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.284:298) : avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=3372 comm=su name=lastlog dev="dm-0" ino=659972 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lastlog_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.285:299) : avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=3372 comm=su path=/var/log/lastlog dev="dm-0" ino=659972 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lastlog_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.342:301) : avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=3373 comm=xscreensaver-co path=/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:xserver_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.343:302) : avc:  denied  { read } for  pid=3373 comm=xscreensaver-co name=.Xauthority dev="dm-4" ino=15466502 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:xauth_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.343:303) : avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=3373 comm=xscreensaver-co path=/home/ken/.Xauthority dev="dm-4" ino=15466502 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:xauth_home_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.538:315) : avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=3374 comm=su name=lastlog dev="dm-0" ino=659972 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lastlog_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.538:316) : avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=3374 comm=su path=/var/log/lastlog dev="dm-0" ino=659972 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lastlog_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.539:318) : avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=3382 comm=su capability=setgid  scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:19.543:319) : avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=3382 comm=xscreensaver-co path=/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:xserver_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:22.153:336) : avc:  denied  { read write } for  pid=3386 comm=su name=lastlog dev="dm-0" ino=659972 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lastlog_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:22.153:337) : avc:  denied  { open } for  pid=3386 comm=su path=/var/log/lastlog dev="dm-0" ino=659972 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:lastlog_t:s0 tclass=file permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:22.153:339) : avc:  denied  { setgid } for  pid=3395 comm=su capability=setgid  scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=capability permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:22.157:340) : avc:  denied  { connectto } for  pid=3395 comm=xscreensaver-co path=/tmp/.X11-unix/X0 scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:xserver_t:s0-s0:c0.c1023 tclass=unix_stream_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:21.901:322) : avc:  denied  { create } for  pid=3386 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_selinux_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:21.901:323) : avc:  denied  { bind } for  pid=3386 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=netlink_selinux_socket permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:21.901:324) : avc:  denied  { compute_av } for  pid=3386 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:object_r:security_t:s0 tclass=security permissive=1 
----
type=AVC msg=audit(19/07/18 10:24:21.905:329) : avc:  denied  { setsched } for  pid=3386 comm=su scontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tcontext=system_u:system_r:apmd_t:s0 tclass=process permissive=1
```

There must be a neater way to do this without disabling selinux for acpi

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for a "neater" way, making a service start graphical programs is *right out.* It's poor design, not only because of SELinux.

Change the command to `/usr/bin/loginctl lock-sessions`. This broadcasts a "lock" signal to all graphical sessions, and each session can react to it internally (e.g. start a locker without any SELinux troubles). Chances are that LXDE might already support it.

If LXDE does not react to the lock signal, run a helper which does:

- [xss-lock](https://bitbucket.org/raymonad/xss-lock/src)
- [grawity/systemd-lock-handler](https://nullroute.eu.org/code/systemd-lock-handler)
- [WhyNotHugo/systemd-lock-handler](https://github.com/WhyNotHugo/systemd-lock-handler)